# Changing an element to absolute postion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a set of elements `position:absolute` using jQuery and I've written the below code. The problem is, I cannot chain the two loops into one where the offset end up returning the same value for each element.

```
$(navSelector + ' > li', this).each(function () {
    var position = $(this).offset().left - $(this).parent().scrollLeft();
    $(this).attr('data-absolute-position', (position + 5));
});

$(navSelector + ' > li', this).each(function () {
    $(this).css({
       'left': $(this).data('absolute-position'),
       'position': 'absolute'
    });
});
```

if I combine the two loops as following the `position` will return the same value for each `ul > li` element. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$(navSelector + ' > li', this).each(function () {
            var position = $(this).offset().left - $(this).parent().scrollLeft();
            $(this).attr('data-absolute-position', (position + 5)).css({
                'left': $(this).data('absolute-position'),
                'position': 'absolute'
            });;
        });
```

Sorry guys but the HTML is a bit complex and I've found a work around to my issue. I've simply added a `setTimeout` and the change works fine! Bt What I'm not sure is, whether this is the best way to do it?

```
$(navSelector + ' > li', this).each(function(){
            var el = $(this);
            var curPos = el.offset().left - el.parent().scrollLeft();
            var absPos = curPos + 5;

            el.attr('data-absolute-position',absPos);

            setTimeout(function(){
                el.css({
                    'left': absPos,
                    'position': 'absolute'
                });
            },0);

        })
```

Comment: [mcve] with the HTML, please.

Comment: Because it has the same position I think. Can you create fiddle?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle and show

Comment: Look at it https://jsfiddle.net/9upL98gb/. I'm not sure if this are similar to what you want. If it is, then it will have the same logic.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the original is complex; you shouldn't be posting it but an example, which can be minimized. Answers shouldn't be added to the question but posted separately.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to say.

Probably you can try to find out your total number of li then do a for loop in the each function and return the value.

Comment: Agree man. He needs to declare a variable outside which can hold and add number. (+1)

Comment: I saw your fiddle and that's something new to me. I have never come across or tried to do that before lol. Is that a combination of each and for loop?

Comment: I think jQuery each loop does the same. Much of it I think. Haha. I use it all the time. even [].filter() can be used. For me it's much cleaner than for loop.

Comment: The one you are using is not jQuery right? May I know what language is that?

Comment: Plain javascript. I used jQuery before but when we built a big system. It became laggy and so much delay. So I just used plain javascript instead of  jQuery. But some of the library are good such as reactjs and angular. I just use jQuery in small project.

Comment: OOO! I see. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my question with an working answer! sorry for not providing the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

A fiddle will be helpful. But as per my understanding of your requirement, you can't have it chained in one line. You need to split as follows:

```
$(navSelector + ' > li', this).each(function () {
    var position = $(this).offset().left - $(this).parent().scrollLeft();
    $(this).attr('data-absolute-position', (position + 5));
    $(this).css({
       'left': $(this).data('absolute-position'),
       'position': 'absolute'
    });
});
```

With the following code that you gave, maybe its not able to properly find and apply the css effect to element.

```
$(this).attr('data-absolute-position', (position + 5)).css({
                'left': $(this).data('absolute-position'),
                'position': 'absolute'
            });;
```